# JQuery masonry doesn't work after ajax click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a problem with my ajax code. I created a **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/mustafaozturk74/f396nju7/)** from jsfiddle.net

In this demo you can see the grid system it is working fine. But when you click the button for load more post the problem will be come on that time.

What is the problem in my code? Anyone can help me in this regard ?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
function loadMore() {
    $('.posts-holder').append('<div class="kesif-gonderi-alani" style="height:300px; background:blue;">6</div>');
    $('.posts-holder').append('<div class="kesif-gonderi-alani" style="height:300px;">7</div>');
    $('.posts-holder').append('<div class="kesif-gonderi-alani" style="height:300px;">8</div>');
     $('.posts-holder').append('<div class="kesif-gonderi-alani" style="height:300px;">9</div>');
     $('.posts-holder').append('<div class="kesif-gonderi-alani" style="height:300px;">10</div>');

  }
  function ajax() {
    // fake request
    setTimeout(function(){
      loadMore();
      test();
    },1500);
  }
  $('.button').bind('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    ajax();

  });
  function test(){
  var $container = $(".posts-holder");
  $container.imagesLoaded(function() {
    $container.masonry({
      columnWidth: ".kesif-gonderi-alani",
      itemSelector: ".kesif-gonderi-alani"
    });
  });
  }
  test();
});
```

Comment: can you show where are you using ajax here?

Comment: @markoffden go down  to see ajax  codes

Comment: well, if you call your function ajax() it does not mean it will have ajax functionality by default

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/methods.html#appended) `append` method insted of jQuery one.
I've uploaded in your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f396nju7/2/) the function `loadMore`.

```
function loadMore() {

  var $items = $('<div class="kesif-gonderi-alani" style="height:300px;">6</div><div class="kesif-gonderi-alani" style="height:300px;">7</div><div class="kesif-gonderi-alani" style="height:300px;">8</div><div class="kesif-gonderi-alani" style="height:300px;">9</div><div class="kesif-gonderi-alani" style="height:300px;">10</div>');

      $('.posts-holder').append($items)
      // add and lay out newly appended items
      .masonry('appended', $items);
}
```

The `append` method of Masonry need a jQuery object. So in your real ajax call you will create these new object and put them as argument in the `append` method.